# Simple hit counter (as block)?

Tags: 7

I need to implement kind of a hit counter for the entire page (so how often the site was visited) in D7.

For D6 we got the [Counter](http://drupal.org/project/counter) module, but is there any simple way to do it? Perhaps with a custom block and some PHP code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the core Statistics module as described [here](http://www.jonathansantos.com/index.php/software-toolbox/drupal/118-drupal-7-hitpage-view-counter-for-articles).

You could use [Visitors](http://drupal.org/project/visitors) module.

I use [Google Analytics](http://drupal.org/project/google_analytics) but this might be too heavy if you need a basic solution.

Comment: The link to the core module instructions no longer works (Jan 21 2015)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [mostpopular module](http://www.drupal.org/project/mostpopular) for this.

> The module is pre-packaged with several services including:
>
> 1. Drupal - Most Viewed pages (using Statistics module)
> 2. Drupal - Most Commented pages (from simple database query)
> 3. Google Analytics - Most Viewed pages
> 4. AddThis.com - Most Shared pages
> 5. Disqus.com - Most Commented pages The system defines Drupal hooks to allow new services to be created, which can pull data from third
>      party providers or internally from Drupal.
>
> The system also provides an API to help service plugins normalize their results and exclude certain pages, as configured by the administrator.

For more detail about the module you could visit [this](http://www.drupalmostpopular.com/documentation).