# Is it possible to include countdowns in nodes?

Tags: javascript

I need to include countdowns in nodes of a particular content type

I looked around but couldn't find a countdown module that allows simultaneous active countdowns.

Any ideas, suggestions are welcome

Comment: you mean visitors countdown ?

Comment: check this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18207/simple-hit-counter-as-block

Comment: @Bala 'countdown' != 'counter' :)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I meant a countdown to an event. Ex : http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2011/12/countdown-jquery/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a countdown timer, the [Javascript Timer](https://drupal.org/project/jstimer) module is what you need.

> The Javascript Timer module provides a timer api that can hook html elements to javascript widget objects. This is useful if you want a moving timer/clock or a widget that updates every second. It comes with widgets for a count-down timer, a count-up timer, and a clock. It uses jQuery and a single event loop to handle as many timers as you need on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

There is [jquery_countdown](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) for general purpose countdown display, though the way you would integrate this depends on what you want to countdown. Using this module it is quite easy to display a countdown based on a node field value. Unfortunately there is no display configuration in the UI. But you could use `hook_node_view()` to add a countdown to a node view like this:

```
$node->content['countdown'] = theme('jquery_countdown', array(
  'id' => 'jquery_countdown-' . $node->nid,
  'options' => array(
    'until' => date("F d, Y g:i:s a", $some_timestamp),
    'format' => 'dHMS',
    'compact' => TRUE,
  ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JQuery Countdown Timer](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown_timer) module.

[image]

> This is a lightweight module that provides a block with a jQuery
>   countdown timer. This module uses only jQuery and css and does not use
>   any images.

also check this https://drupal.org/project/countdown